# How to optimise SQL query performance

Tags: sql, performance, hex

## introduction

I'm doing a query multiple times (one query per "service" in a given location). The query, performance results and size of dataset are below.
Please give me advice on how to optimize the performance. Thanks

## size of dataset

- services table: 8 thousand rows
- how_rates_policies: 0.2 million rows
- how_rates: 1.7 million rows

## performance results

#### Botswana

- Number of services: 4
- Delay: 7sec
- Delay per service: about 2s/service

#### Cape Town CBD

- Number of services: 34
- Delay: 4.5min
- Delay per service: about 7s/service

## query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER= [i removed the db user name here to censor it] PROCEDURE `spx_GetRatesForProduct`(productId INT, priceCode VARCHAR(2), inDate DATETIME, outDate DATETIME)
BEGIN
    DECLARE endRateDate DATETIME;

    SET endRateDate := (SELECT MAX(date_to)
    FROM  how_rates_policies hrp
    WHERE hrp.product_id = productId and hrp.price_code = priceCode and hrp.date_to >= outDate);

-- SELECT endRateDate = IFNULL(endRateDate, '19700101');

IF endRateDate = '19700101' THEN   
   SELECT * FROM  how_rates_policies hrp INNER JOIN how_rates hr ON hrp.id = hr.what_rates_policies_id
    WHERE hrp.product_id = productId 
        AND hrp.price_code = priceCode 
        AND hrp.date_from <= inDate 
        AND hr.rate_category = 'VAL' 
    ORDER BY hrp.date_to;

ELSE
    SELECT * FROM  how_rates_policies hrp 
        INNER JOIN how_rates hr 
            ON hrp.id = hr.what_rates_policies_id
    WHERE hrp.product_id = productId 
        AND hrp.price_code = priceCode 
        AND hrp.date_from <= outDate 
        AND hrp.date_to >= inDate
        AND hrp.date_to <= endRateDate
        AND hr.rate_category = 'VAL' 
    ORDER BY hrp.date_to;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you make clear of your query. Where does the column outDate , inDate, productId  and priceCode  come from. Which table exactly ?

Comment: These are not column names, these are parameters that are passed into the stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to give us the name of your RDBMS, and also the execution plan.

Comment: RDBMS is MariaDB and i will have to do more research to know what an execution plan is

Answer (score 0):

the problem was it wasnt running the query the amount of times we guessed it was (Botswana: 4 times; and Cape Town CBD: 34 times) it was in fact running it a lot more times